# Unity 8 scopes: changing the card color has no effect

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, scopes, unity8

The example scope that comes with the ubuntu-sdk implements a client for the OpenWeatherMap API.

If I specify "card-background" in the category renderer template (because I want to have background for my cards) nothing happens. Here is what the code looks like:

```
const static string WEATHER_TEMPLATE = R"(
{
    "schema-version": 1,
    "template": {
        "category-layout": "carousel",
        "card-layout": "horizontal",
        "card-size": "small",
        "card-background": "color:///#0F0F0F"
    },
    "components": {
        "title": "title",
        "art" : {
            "field": "art"
        },
        "subtitle": "subtitle"
    }
}
)";
```

Unless I change the "card-layout" to vertical, the color is not added as a background.

Interestingly, if the card-layout is set to vertical, then the cards have blue backgrounds but their bottom 10% is cropped out. Anyone has seen this before?

Comment: I too have noticed that the background color is only effective with vertical card layouts.  I don't know if this is a design choice or a bug.